# /proc/devices still shows unregistered device

Tags: linux, character, device, linux-device-driver

I am learning to write my first Linux char driver, but can't seem to make it work as expected.

The code for the driver module's init and exit functions are below:

```
static int __init one_init(void)
{
    int result;
    printk(KERN_DEBUG "In ones init call");
    result = alloc_chrdev_region(&onedev, 0, 4, "one");
    printk("Allocated device major: %d, first minor: %d",MAJOR(onedev),MINOR(onedev));
    return 0;
}

static void __exit one_exit(void)
{
    unregister_chrdev_region(onedev,4);
    printk(KERN_DEBUG "In ones exit call");
}
```

My device still shows in `/proc/devices` after I unload my driver, whose exit function calls `unregister_chrdev_region`.

The `dmesg` command prints shows that my driver's init and exit calls were made.

I saw a few related questions, but the answers did not solve my seemingly simple problem.

What am I doing or expecting wrong?

Comment: As can be inferred, onedev is of type dev_t.

Comment: You are not checking `result` in `one_init`. Maybe the call fails, and so the region is not associated to this driver, but with a previous incarnation of your module. _Never ignore_ error when programming kernel code, not even in testing code.

Comment: Thanks, I will change it to check the return value. However, the  'printk' statement following the 'alloc' shows me a proper major/minor number. Also, I can see the newly allocated device numbers in '/proc/devices'!

Answer (score -1):

Use 'rmmod modulename' in the terminal. This should unload the module and remove the associations.